# Strong induction with recursive definition function

Tags: induction, transfinite-recursion

Look at following recursive function definition for function $F :\mathbb{N}​\times\mathbb{N}​ \to \mathbb{N}$​:
$$
\begin{split}
F(x,0) & = 0\\
F(x,n) & = x + F(x, n-1)
\end{split}
$$

Prove by induction over $n$ that $F(1,n) = n$, for all $n \ge 0$.

Studing for my discrete mathematics test. And came over this question, and I dont really know how to solve it.

Did the base case but I dont know how to continue. Tested all kinds of stuff, but I've got stuck in the step case.
Came as far as:
$$
\begin{split}
F(x,n+1)&=x+F(x,n-1+1)\\ 
        &=x+F(x,n)=\\
        & = x + x + F(x,n-1)\dots\text{ then I get stuck or dont know if im doing it right.}
\end{split} 
$$
Another example...
$$
\begin{split}
F(x,n+1)&=x+F(x,n+1-1)...... (n+1)\\
 &=F(1,n+1)x+F(x,F(1,n+1-1))=x+F(x,F(1,n))\\
 &=x+F(x,n)\dots\text{ then I get stuck again.}
\end{split}
$$
I don't know if I am doing anything right. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Try $F(n,x) = n x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting $x=1$,
we get

$\begin{split}
F(1,0) & = 0\\
F(1,n) & = 1 + F(1, n-1)
\end{split}
$.

If $F(1, n-1) = n-1$
(true for $n=1$),
then
$F(1,n)  
= 1 + F(1, n-1)
=n
$.

In general,
as Cesareo pointed out,
this same argument
can be used to prove that
$F(x, n) = nx$.

The two-variable form
is just used to confuse.
In addition,
you don't need strong induction -
regular induction is enough.